# Combining two pre defined functions

Tags: python, function

I was asked to create a function to give a square of a value. Here is the defined function:

```py
 def square(x):
    print(x**2)
```

secondly I was asked to define another function to check weather the number is odd or even:

```py
def oddeve(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
     print ("{} is even".format(x))
    else:
     print ("{} is odd".format(x))
```

However now they want me to use both the function together to check whether the square is odd or even. Can anyone help me with how to combine two pre defined functions?

Comment: call `oddeven` with the `square` of `x`...create a function that does that

Comment: You should modify your functions to ``return`` the value instead of printing the value. You can still print the returned value later by putting a print around the (nested) function call. E.g. ``print( oddeve(square(x)) )`` - the outer function(s) will use the returned value of the inner function(s) as their parameter.

Comment: Then you'll be able to call `oddeve(square(x))`

Comment: Did you really not see any examples of this in your lessons/textbook/etc.?

Comment: I tried using the return function but I am still getting error. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Here is what I did def square(x):
    return(x**2) and def oddeve(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
     return("even")
    else:
     return("odd") . However when I am using oddeve(square(x)) its still not working

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call one function inside of the other function. However, this requires that you don't print out the value, but rather return it:

```
 def square(x):
    return(x**2)
```

Now you can simply call:

```
oddeve(square(x))
```

For example, if x = 4, `square(4)` returns 16, and `oddeve(16)` prints out that it is even.

Comment: Okay I got it now. Thanks